# Finding detail of a Locale?

Tags: angular, localization

I am using Angular 5 in my application. On supplying the locale data to its currency pipe, the currency symbol (`USD`, `INR`. etc.) are shown either before or after the amount. There is a space in some and in some cases it is stuck to the amount. I would like to know if this behaviour is documented somewhere so that I know how an amount would be displayed in a locale. I learnt that it follows the CLDR (http://cldr.unicode.org/) specification but don't know where to find locale-specific settings. Any help is appreciated.